# Check Internet Speed test VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to check internet speed from vb.net app.
I've tried this code but it does not give me correct information.

```
Dim netI() As NetworkInterface = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces
Label3.Text = netI(0).Speed 
Label3.Text = Label3.Text / 1048576
```

Whats basicly i need is to know my internet speed test download in mbps

Comment: That's not internet speed, but the network card connection speed instead! What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, i need to know from vb.net app whats my internet speed in mbps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a logic to figure it by your self.

First you find out a file which can be downloaded from internet.

Then convert the **file size** into **Megabits** or **Kilobits**. The format you want to measure (Mbps or Kbps)

You know the download speed is measured **Megabits per second** or **Kilobits per second**

First capture the start time

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now
```

Down load the file

```
Dim web_client As WebClient = New WebClient        
web_client.DownloadFile("URL", filename)
```

Now capture the end time.

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now
```

Now you can calculate the download speed by using math functions.

= file size/(start Time In Seconds-end Time In Seconds)

Notes: Use only `DownloadFile` of `WebClient`. Because this method blocks while downloading the file. Do not use `DownloadFileAsync`.

Comment: How about a StopWatch? Start after you create the web client. Use Start, Stop and Elapsed

Comment: @Mary Yes. That's a much better idea.